# Centering text in Dynamic Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image that is dynamic: 100% width and 100% height, how do I keep the text inside in the center vertically and horizontally no matter what size it is?

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/h9y8umr2/

```css
html, body{
  margin:0px;

}
.wrapper{
position:relative;
}
img{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.text-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-25%;
  margin-top:-25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="http://www.wildlifetrusts.org/sites/default/files/images/Planting%20along%20realigned%20River%20Chelt%20Gloucs%20WT,%20EA%20and%20landowner2%20comp.jpg">
<div class="text-wrapper">

<h2>Sample Text</h2>
<p>Text Sample</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `transform: translate()` to **center** the text. 
By the way, it's better to use [CSS Flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) -  [`fiddle here`](https://jsfiddle.net/5yv01q8s/) :)

```css
html, body{
  margin:0px;

}
.wrapper{
position:relative;
}
img{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.text-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="http://www.wildlifetrusts.org/sites/default/files/images/Planting%20along%20realigned%20River%20Chelt%20Gloucs%20WT,%20EA%20and%20landowner2%20comp.jpg">
<div class="text-wrapper">

<h2>Sample Text</h2>
<p>Text Sample</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show me how it's done in flexbox, I was playing around with it but I wasn't able to use it, I would love to get to use it.

Comment: The flexbox is really nice to use in any markup situation, just read the doc. There's a properties for the container and for the child items. Feel free to ask questions :) akhxtern@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I removed margin-left: -25% and margin-top: -25% and added margin: 0 auto; and that fixed it

```
    .text-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

[Updated fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/h9y8umr2/2/)

Comment: If you re-size the browser or the box in jsfiddle, you can see that it's not actually centered unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only problem is your text-wrapper class.

If you write top:50% and left:50%, the top-left corner of your text div will be the exact center of your img.

You just have to adjust your margin-left and margin-top to the size of your text then (write width/2 and height/2 of your text for the margins) :)